# is there an alternative select and redirect to set a session?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This post relates to a previous that i posted but the question is different now:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671809/selection-on-change-set-session-not-working/5671816#5671816

When i select the select field in AJAX the session is set and the page is refreshed to display the value inside the session. How can i without a refresh have it where a handle like this

```
$("#output").something
```

check every second by sending an ajax request to `ajax.php?action=checksessionShipping` and that ajax file would return a true if the session is set or a false if not set. so once it detects that the session is set (btw, the session would be `$_SESSION['shipping']` its on that other stack page.) it returns the value to a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind, this is the quick and dirty code. It should not be used in production as is because it's not very secure or scalable. But, it'll get you started:

You could do something like this in your HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">

</div><!-- END: #mydiv -->

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax.php?action=checksessionShipping',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {},
          complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            //called when complete
          },
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

            if (data.session_set == true)
                $("#mydiv").html(data.shipping);
                clearInterval(myInterval);

          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //called when there is an error
          }
        });

    }, 1000);

</script>
```

And something like this in your PHP:

```
<?php

session_start()
$arrReturn = array('session_set' => FALSE);

if (!empty($_SESSION['shipping'])) {

    $arrReturn['session_set'] = TRUE;
    $arrReturn['shipping'] = $_SESSION['shipping'];

}

echo json_encode($arrReturn);
?>
```

Comment: whats wrong with the above in production? other than always cleaning the session file before use?

Comment: I'm just saying that you should provide error reporting and such before using it in production. The code above isn't necessarily insecure, but it could quickly become insecure when you start modifying it to make it work in your situation if you're not careful.